# jquery how to get the first list item with display:none

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, so I have this div which contains a ul:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert($('#slider ul li[display="none"]:first').text());
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
li
{
display:inline;
margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider" style="width:100%; overflow-x:hidden"><ul><li style="display:none">Steve 1</li><li style="display:none">Frank</li><li>Tim</li><li>Steve</li><li>Frank</li><li>Tim</li><li>Steve</li><li>Frank</li><li>Tim</li><li>Steve</li><li>Frank</li><li>Tim</li><li>Steve</li><li>Frank</li><li>Tim</li><li>Steve</li><li>Frank</li><li>Tim</li><ul>
</div>
<button type="button" style="float:left">Previous</button><div style="float:right">Next</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I wanted to happen is that when you press the Previous button it would find the first item in the list with display none and show a message with it's content. In this case Steve1.

So I used `$('#slider ul li[display="none"]:first')` which means it should find the div named slider and it's first list item in the ul with display:none.

I get a blank back in the message.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

I think it's got to do with the attribute part which I constructed from:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: It doesn't work because there's no such thing as `display="none"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#slider ul li[style="display:none"]:first')
```

Square brackets select elements based on attributes. There was no `display` attribute. But the `style` attribute can be used. If the `style` attribute has other styles than just `display:none` then you can use a RegExp selector:

```
$('#slider ul li[style*="display:none"]:first')
```

The asterik (`*`) means that the string can exist anywhere inside the actual value of the attribute.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TAv3d/

Docs for jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Alternatively you can use functions for DOM traversal (and it's a bit faster):

```
$('#slider').children('ul').children('li').filter('[style="display:none"]').first();
```

Comment: Please note that it might require the semicolon to work [style="display:none;"]

Answer (score 10):

`$('#slider ul li:hidden:first')` is what you are looking for

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

`:hidden` matches the following conditions, according to the link above

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> 1. They have a CSS display value of none.
> 2. They are form elements with type="hidden".
> 3. Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> 4. An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.